# Offsetting tracer particles in a fluid simulation

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I am working on an animation where I am using fluid tracer particles as a *smoke flow* object, and I have run into a problem. To get an idea of what I am trying to do, see my test render (of a simpler scene) at https://youtu.be/NovKf-hDN48

Basically, I have a fluid with tracer particles that are on fire. And of course some dynamic paint going on and stuff , but that is not relevant to my question.

Anyway, I need there to be many parts being set alight at different times (so multiple separate fluid domains), and while it is easy to use *Offset* to start the different fluid sims at different times, I have found no way to translate this to the tracer particles. They will always start off at the first frame. I cannot set different particle systems on fire (with the smoke simulator) at different times.

Does anybody know of a way to get this to work? Even a crude workaround would be helpful.

**Edit after more experiments:**

The obvious workaround is to set the inflow objects to start at different times (by keyframing the *enable* property), but apart from the fact that this doesn't work (see below), even if it did, I would have to rebake the fluid sim for any small change in timing, which is cumbersome to say the least.

And yes, there seems to be a bug with the tracer particles, so if the *inflow* object is not enabled at the beginning of the animation (frame 1) the tracer particles won't work at all. They just don't appear with the fluid when the *inflow* object gets enabled.

My workaround for the time being (for whoever runs into this problem in the future) is to have the *inflow* objects enabled for the first frame, and then disabled until I want them start for real. Then hide the *fluid particle* object until the particles are supposed to be seen.

Still, even with this workaround, I would be happy to hear if anyone has a smoother solution. Yeah, I realise this is quite a niche problem...

Comment: Hi Jbergman, I think I got it. Are you still active here? I'm quite busy this days, so I'm not going to post it right now. The solution is a little cumbersome but is not difficult. Actually, after realizing it, I just decided to go on and don't use particles at all in this shot.